# Write transparency to bitmap using unsafe with the original colors preserved?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, transparency, unsafe

In this code I'm creating Transparent bitmap but coloring the pixels in the List testpoints in yellow.
How can I keep make it Transparent but the pixels to be coloring or keep with the original colors of them instead yellow ?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g;
    g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpBackClouds);
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    g.Dispose();
    BitmapData b1 = bmpBackClouds.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0,
                    bmpBackClouds.Width, bmpBackClouds.Height), 
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    int stride = b1.Stride;
    int i;

    System.IntPtr Scan0 = b1.Scan0;

    unsafe
    {
        byte* p;

        for (i = 0; i < testpoints.Count; i++)
        {
            p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;

            p += (int)testpoints[i].Y * stride + (int)testpoints[i].X * 4;

            p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;
            p[0] = (byte)0;
            p[3] = (byte)255;
        }
    }
    bmpBackClouds.UnlockBits(b1);
    bmpBackClouds.Save(@"c:\temp\yellowbmpcolor.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: `p[3] = (byte)255;`makes the pixel opaque. change it to `p[3] = (byte)0;` to make it transparaent. Don't touch the other bytes to keep their original color.

Comment: I changed it to p[3] = (byte)0; what i get now on the hard disk is empty black image when i edit it i see it all white without anything inside. Maybe iy\s something with how i init the bmpBackClouds in the first time in the constructor ? bmpBackClouds = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Comment: What is `testPoints` ?

Comment: testpoints is a List<PointF> contain the pixels coordinates to color.

Comment: If you open a png image with paint program it is white because paint can not handle png formats. Open it with gib or photoshop(if you have it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code will work fine with a tiny correction:

Delete the part where you delete the image:

```
Graphics g;
g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpBackClouds);
g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
g.Dispose();
```

This will wipe out the image and you'll end up with nothing in it.

Then after changing this

```
        p[1] = p[2] = (byte)255;
        p[0] = (byte)0;
        p[3] = (byte)255;
```

to that:

```
        p[3] = 0;
```

the portions in your testpoints list will be transparent, with their color channels intact.

Which is somewhat hard to see ;-)

The best test is to read it back and to restore the alpha channel and voila, the original image is back!

**Note** In case you wanted to make the whole `Bitmap` transparent by those first lines - This doesn't work. There is a bug in `GDI`'s treatment of transparency; presumably to save time it doesn't preserve the original colors when you try to use it to make part of an image or all of it transparent. This it true both for `Graphics.Clear` and for the other `Graphics` methods like `Graphics.FillRectangle` etc..

..so if you want to clear an image's alpha channel completely, use code like the above to do so, obviously without the list and with loops over all pixels..

Comment: What you did is exactly the same with "g.Clear(Color.Transparent);". So keep "g.Clear(Color.Transparent);" and dont lock unlock image. There is no bug at all. It does make the bitmap transparent

Comment: Wrong on both counts. Clear will clear the image. Obviously. Which is not what was asked for. And the Transparency bug is well known, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236422/why-does-system-drawing-graphics-blank-the-rgb-channels-when-alpha-0)

Comment: Clear means clear. No bug. It zeros everything. You didnt notice OP's first comment. The bitmap does not contain any color information to preserve. With "g.Clear(Color.Transparent);" OP sees a black image (after saving it) and he thinks it is not transparent. That is why he asked the question.

Comment: Your anwser is not wrong. If you want to zero only alpha your code is right. But, in the context of the question is unnecessary. OP fills yellow color to the image and the rest is transparent. But after saving he sees yellow and black around it and thinks that the black is not transparent. Probably opened the image with paint and saw white and yellow.