# Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent) draw blurry text inside tab control

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I have my user control inside a tab. Text inside user control is blurry. Please find the code of user control paint event below

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     //Avoid redrawing the control unnecessarily
     if(redraw)
     {
         using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
         {
                g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                draw(g, ClientRectangle);
         }
     }
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(buffer, Point.Empty);
}
```

I noticed following things if I place my control inside Tab control available in VS toolbox.

1) Text drawn in user control is blurry

2) Paint event triggered three times. Due to conditional redraw, drawing logic will be executed once and existing buffer will be drawn on 2nd and 3rd time

3) If I use g.Clear(Color.White), text looks good

The line g.Clear is supposed to clear the Bitmap(buffer) and fill it with specified color. It also clears the state of the graphics object. If I use any color other than Transparent, text is not blurry.

Is there any notable difference between g.Clear(Color.White) and g.Clear(Color.Transparent)?

Note: Color.White is just an example. Any named color gets rid of the problem. Also occurs only with Tab control

**Edit:**
Blurred and correct images are available below

[image: Blurry Text]

[image: Normal image]

Comment: I don't see any code that draws text. I only see you draw an image..

Comment: Text is present in the image. In method draw, all the logic for drawing the control is present

Comment: So either the image is blurry of the way you draw it. Not knowing how it gets created and not seeing the result it isn't possible to help.. Try to post the image!

Comment: @TaW, attached both the images for comparison

Comment: Interesting. Looks pixelated. The image probably was created with a lower resolution. Do make sure you control the resolutions (image.HorizontalResolution etc) and stay with always the same. And of course you will usually get much worse results when drawing text to a bitmap than by letting the system rendering it to a control. Did you use DrawToBitmap or DrawString? Set smoothingmode and textrendering hints?

Comment: If I directly place my control on a Form or panel, image is drawn in high quality. But if the same image is drawn when my control is placed inside a Tab, it looks pixelated. Do you have any idea about this behavior? One thing to note is, it happens only if I use Graphics.Clear with Color.Transparent as parameter

Comment: Sounds a little as if the clear might leave things on the slate. Why not clear with the color you actually want?? Assuming you actually mean a TabPage, not a TabControl maybe `g.Clear(tabPage1.BackColor); - The discussion in the answer is confusing. There are no states you can return to unless to save them: Either by saving the steps to create them or by saving the results, i.e. bitmaps.

Comment: The sample images confirm my speculation. The text is anti-aliased, and you're drawing it multiple times on top of itself, so it turns out blurry. [Related reading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060614-00/?p=30873). If you *absolutely* must draw text multiple times on top of itself, you must ensure that it is not anti-aliased. Of course, then it'll look crappy for a different reason. It is still unclear to me why you cannot redesign your painting logic so this problem goes away.

Comment: @CodyGray, Code for reproducing this in a simple control is available in this MSDN forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/761752e7-5921-4aa2-8b8b-0345ad921894/bug-in-graphicsclear-method-?forum=winforms

Comment: I think its possibly a bug or something that was intentionally left alone

Comment: Updated my answer with an assessment of your linked sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what universe does it make sense to "clear" with a *transparent* color?

Color.Transparent is…transparent. Defined as the absence of color. If you fill with a transparent color, you fill with nothing. Emptiness. Transparency.

If you fill something that had text on it with a transparent color, it will have no effect and the text will remain there. Then, if you draw the same text back on top of it, you will see blurriness (at least, assuming the text is anti-aliased; if it's not, nothing will change).

Any color other than Color.Transparent will work to clear the area because they are *opaque* colors. Meaning that they are the opposite of transparent. You can't see through them, so they actually cover up what is behind them.

---

You've also tried too hard to optimize the code. When a Paint event handler is called, the item *needs to be painted*. The operating system already takes care of optimizing this for you. So the `if (redraw)` check is neither necessary nor a good idea. Just fill with your background color, and draw the image or text on top of it.

---

**Update:** I was pointed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/761752e7-5921-4aa2-8b8b-0345ad921894/bug-in-graphicsclear-method-?forum=winforms) to code that supposedly reproduces the problem. Like Moonlight Sheng, I was unable to reproduce the described problem with that code.

This is not surprising. In the linked code, the call to `g.Clear` is completely superfluous for two reasons. First, as I have already explained, clearing with `Color.Transparent` is essentially a no-op—it does absolutely nothing. Second, the line immediately following fills the entire image rectangle with a solid white brush. This serves the purpose of "clearing" the drawing surface, making it all white. You could have accomplished the same thing with `g.Clear(Color.White)`. The text is then drawn on top of this white background, and finally the image is drawn onto the control. This works perfectly because there are never any "transparent" areas. Whenever the image is drawn on top of the control, it covers up (therefore erasing) everything that was there previously. Absolutely no blurriness. As such, this has nothing to do with the use of `Graphics.Clear` or `Color.Transparent`.

I suppose that since you are overriding `OnLayout`, you intend for this control to be used with either its Anchor or Dock properties set. So I set the Dock property to Fill in my test project, and re-ran the application. Again, I fail to reproduce the problem. However, I do notice that when rapidly resizing the container form, I can produce "tearing" effects or other visual artifacts. For example, when I make the form really small, I see the text drawn multiple times:

[image]

This is a race condition caused by the rapid resizing of the form. The dimensions of the client rectangle are changing too quickly, and the newly-exposed regions of the form are not being erased. Let me see if I can explain what is actually happening.

- When the form (and control) changes to size *X*, you destroy the old buffer image and create a new buffer image of size *X*. Then you call `DrawString` to draw text into it. The image is too narrow to fit the entire string on one line, so it wraps the "100" onto a second line. The image is then drawn onto the form, and everything looks fine.
- Then the form (and control) changes to size *Y*. So you again destroy the old buffer image and create a new buffer image of size *Y*. This time, the width has increased so that when the text is drawn, everything fits on one line. The image is then drawn onto the form.
- Oh, but wait. Size *Y* is wider than size *X*, but also shorter (less tall). So when you draw this new buffer to the form, it doesn't cause the previous area to be erased. This is why you see the old "100", wrapped onto the second line, remain visible.

It's very difficult to explain, and I imagine harder still to understand, unless you already know how painting works.

The important part is that there is a simple solution: set the form's `ResizeRedraw` property to `true`, ensuring that a Paint event gets raised every time the form is resized. Forcing a repaint in the control's `OnLayout` event handler method would also work (`this.Invalidate()`), like so:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
   Image buffer;
   public MyControl()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
   {
      if (buffer != null)
      {
         buffer.Dispose();
         buffer = null;
      }
      base.OnLayout(e);

      this.Invalidate();  // force a repaint after the layout has changed
   }

   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
      if (buffer == null)
      {
         buffer = new Bitmap(ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);

         using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
         {
            //g.Clear(Color.Transparent);  // pointless
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);
            using (Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular))
            {
               g.DrawString("Simple text 100", f, Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle);
            }
         }
      }
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(buffer, ClientRectangle);
      base.OnPaint(e);
   }
}
```

Anyway, this is not a bug as claimed, but simply a misunderstanding of how the painting subsystem works in Windows.

Incidentally, if you remove that call to `FillRectangle` (which fills the control's client area with solid white), you would see the blurry-text effect that you describe originally. This is occurring for the exact reasons that I have already stated: the text is anti-aliased, and drawing anti-aliased text on top of anti-aliased text produces a "blurry" effect. You cannot fix this in any sensible way. Anti-aliased text absolutely *must* be drawn on top of a solid-color background; it [cannot be drawn on a transparent background](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060614-00/?p=30873). You will need to fill with whatever your form's background color is. By default, that is `SystemColors.Control`.

Comment: I don't want to fill the graphics. I just want to clear the previous state https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't know what "clear the previous state" means. There is no previous state. Every time the Paint event gets raised, the drawing is starting over. You have to draw everything. The `Clear` method just fills with a solid color.

Comment: The if(redraw) part is very essential because I have seen the debugger hitting paint event multiple times. Depending upon the data source and available memory or CPU, it may take few seconds to render the control. In such cases, it will affect form loading.

Comment: The reason I need to clear the previous state is, I am reusing the same bitmap for drawing multiple times. If the paint event is triggered 10 times, same bitmap will be used during these 10 times. If I get the graphics object from an already drawn bitmap, the previous content in bitmap will not be cleared. In order to clear the previous state of Bitmap object, I am using Graphics.Clear method

Comment: Note: using g.Clear(Color.Transparent) fills the bitmap with black color.

Comment: If you want to reuse the same bitmap, you don't need to draw anything onto the bitmap. Its previous contents didn't go anywhere. Just draw the bitmap onto the control. If you want to clear the bitmap, then just don't reuse it.

Comment: for things like changing the ForeColor, BackGroundImage, BackColor, Text of the control dynamically, I will use the existing Bitmap. If Size or layout of the control is changed dynamically, I will dispose the existing Bitmap and create a new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113369/discussion-between-anand-and-cody-gray).

Comment: A new bitmap starts out transparent, clearing it first to black and then to transparent makes it transparent again. `Clear` does not "paint over", it replaces all the pixels regardless of what is already there. In this context it is perfectly valid to clear a bitmap to transparent.

Comment: @CodyGray, Thanks for your answer, I ended up using White color instead of wasting my time with the bug

Comment: @CodyGray instead of being so condescending in your first section you should probably have just informed Kira that the Clear method isn't really a clear but a fill with solid color that you stated in your comments. After reading your answer it still wasn't clear ;) to me why clearing with transparent was such a stupid idea because the naming suggests that I'm clearing the image.

Comment: @Kira you should mark this as the correct answer as this is the most concise information to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to a suggestion how to solve the problem, let me correct two misconceptions..

- > Color.Transparent is essentially a no-op—it does absolutely nothing

Filling/clearing with `Color.Transparent` will make all pixels a **transparent black**: `(0,0,0,0)`.

Contrary to sombody's remarks this is **not nothing**; it is useful and a normal start when one really wants to draw onto a transparent canvas.

Since your result looks wrong with it, you better clear the canvas with the color you really want. If you want to display something like a copy of a `TabPage` you should probably start by filling with the `BackColor` of that page:

```
g.Clear(tapPage1.BackColor);
```

Another remark, this times by you is that :

- > using g.Clear(Color.Transparent) fills the bitmap with black color.

Well, as I said it does fill with **transparent** black (0,0,0,0). It does not fill with **real** black (255,0,0,0).

Transparency is not supported by all imaging software. A notably bad program is the (otherwise great) **IrfanView**, which to this day will display any transparency as black. **Paint .Net** will 'display' it 'correctly' meaning by underlaying it with a checkerboard pattern that shines trough at the transparent pixels..

To make an image 'just' transparent (`alpha=0`) without clearing the `RBG` channels you can use a routine [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082681/write-transparency-to-bitmap-using-unsafe-with-the-original-colors-preserved/26084280?s=27|0.2243#26084280) (although I prefer `Lockbits` to `unsafe`), but as I said, this is not what you want..

**Update**

```
g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

in fact can make the canvas transparent; this is what happens when you use it on a **bitmap**..

..or it brings up the parent's color when you use it on a control. If you use it on a Form, which doesn't have a parent it makes it look black.

Comment: I think the problem is tabPage1.BackColor is transparent. On further analysis I found that, the issue is also resolved by using Graphics.FillRectangle method with any Color other than transparent. I ended up using White color anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: If theTabPage is transparent you could go either use SystemColors.Control or, as you did, use what you like best..